# Delete specific number in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to delete a number (or multiple delete if found more than one result) if the value found in `Column A` is the number I entered in a specific cell, for example B1, in a Google Spreadsheet.

Is there a simple script I could write to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with the find and replace option. Hold command + F and click the more options button. If you want to replace the number 1 in row A with a blank set it like the following and press Replace All:

[image]

If you need a script approach you can do something like the following:

```
  function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var replace = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var newValue = ""

    var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A200").getValues(); //Data to change

    for(var row in values){

      var updatedValues = values[row].map(function(originalValue){
      return originalValue.toString().replace(replace,newValue);
      });

      values[row] = updatedValues;
    }

     sheet.getRange("A1:A200").setValues(values);

   }
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch Torey Price! God bless you :)